# How to setup Proxy Server For HTTP Request on Cloud

Tags: proxy, proxypass

I would like to setup a Proxy server, The job of the proxy server is to be Web Proxy service https://www.techopedia.com/definition/31705/proxy-service

https://www.proxy-service.de/, but on a small scale.

Listen for HTTP Request

Get the http Request , Pass the request to destination as if the Request came from that Proxy Server.

Answer (score 2):

Nginx is the standard solution for reverse proxying.

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

```
location /some/path/ {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com/link/;
}
```

It's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

There are open source proxy servers available which are easy to setup. I suggest **Squid proxy** for your purpose.

Squid supports caching and protocols like HTTP, HTTPS, FTP. Cached proxies are helpful in reducing bandwidth usage. It also provides much needed common features like user authentication and URL filtering.

How to setup Squid proxy-
https://devopscube.com/setup-and-configure-proxy-server/